# Creating files in memory then pushing them into a zip archive using 7-zip commandline?

Tags: c++, stream, zip, 7zip

I'm trying to create zip files on the fly in C++, I'm using 7-zip to try and accomplish this, specifically I want to use the 7-zip commandline (I'm willing to try and modify its source to accomplish this).

Is this possible and if so how should I go about doing it?

Comment: Do you need to avoid just having 7zip make a temporary .zip file and read that file into memory?

Comment: No it should be fine for 7zip to create a zip somewhere on the hard disk. The files to push into it though should go directly into it rather than created then added in.

Comment: Oh, according to another post on SO 7zip doesnt support reading files from stdin, so thats out. You either have to write or find a DEFLATE algorithm implementation and write the file headers, etc. by yourself, or (as you already know) dismantle the 7zip source like you said. That is, unless someone else has done it before and shared their work.

Comment: It's pretty easy to do with zlib if the 7z format isn't a strict requirement.  There is a LZMA sdk available at the 7zip website which may do what you need, but I don't have any direct experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7-zip can compress from `STDIN`, so you start 7z process with certain command line arguments, then put your data into its `STDIN`. For example following:

```
echo foo | 7z a arc.7z -sifoo.txt
echo bar | 7z a arc.7z -sibar.txt
```

will create `arc.7z` file with two files inside: `foo.txt` and `bar.txt` (containing text `foo` and `bar` respectively).

Of course from your program you don't need to call `echo`, only `7z` redirecting `STDIN` with pipes or some other means your OS provides. And you'll have to start `7z` several times if you need to add more than one file.

Comment: Those commandlines do work *but* if I try compressing a zip instead I get an error 'echo foo | 7z a arc.zip -sifoo.txt' => System error:
No such interface supported

Comment: Probably 7-zip does not support compressing from STDIN to every format. Earlier versions did not support compressing to it's own 7z format. If you need to compress to zip format, you'd better to stick to `zlib` or some of it's wrapper instead of 7-zip.

Answer (score 2):

Using [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) with code like this should do the job on windows.

```
#define USEWIN32IOAPI
#include <zip.h>
#include <unzip.h>
#include <iowin32.h>

int toZip(const wchar_t* zipfile,  const char* nameInZip, void* buf, size_t buf_size) 
{
  zlib_filefunc64_def ffunc;
  fill_win32_filefunc64W(&ffunc);
  zipFile zf = zipOpen2_64(zipfile, APPEND_STATUS_CREATE, NULL,&ffunc);
  if(0 == zf)  {
     return -1;
  }

  zip_fileinfo zi;
  zi.tmz_date.tm_sec = zi.tmz_date.tm_min = zi.tmz_date.tm_hour =
    zi.tmz_date.tm_mday = zi.tmz_date.tm_mon = zi.tmz_date.tm_year = 0;
  zi.dosDate = 0;
  zi.internal_fa = 0;
  zi.external_fa = 0;
  zi.dosDate = 0; // no date
  int zip64 = 1; // always zip64
  unsigned long crcFile=0;

  int opt_compress_level(Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
  char* password = 0;
  int err = zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64(zf,nameInZip,&zi,
    NULL,0,NULL,0,NULL,
    (opt_compress_level != 0) ? Z_DEFLATED : 0,
    opt_compress_level,0,
    -MAX_WBITS, DEF_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY,
    password,crcFile, zip64);

  if (ZIP_OK == err) {

    err |= zipWriteInFileInZip (zf,buf,buf_size);
    err |= zipCloseFileInZip(zf);
  }

  err |= zipClose(zf,NULL)

  return err;
}
```